# Custom string format in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to format a string. The below example shows `C$ 123456.00.`

```
Decimal Price = 123456;
string s = Price.ToString("'C$' #,0.00");
```

My question is how do I use the same format in XAML to display the string? I have tried this but only shows `C$` before the decimal.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Price , StringFormat={}C${0}}" />
```

Also is there a way that this format be bound by some string.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your format string to number:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}C$ {0:#,0.00}}" />
```

Comment: Do you mean, is it possible to do smth like `StringFormat={Binding Field}`?

Comment: Correct! I need to format different currency in the same xaml based on the binding